# How 'wild Digimon' in the Digital World fuse or DNA digivolve?

Tags: digimon

Digimon with human partner can easily fuse/DNA digivolve using digivice, like Omegamon in Digimon Adventure Movie.

My question is how 'wild Digimon' fuse/DNA Digivolve? Let's use Royal Knight's Omegamon as an example. How did he came to be?

Comment: I vaguely remember being told that digimon evolution can be seen more like many interconnecting branches, rather than something relatively linear like Pokemon. Perhaps there is a way to have a single digimon naturally digivolve to Omegamon? Are you only looking for evidence from the anime? The video games etc. might provide more information (if maybe not canon).

Comment: @Kozaky I accept information from games too

Answer (score 2):

Digivolution is essentially a lot quicker when it forms a bond with a human. Like you said,  with a Digivice, a Human could share his or her energy and go about facilitating the same.
In the case of wild Digimon, you could consider Digimon to more or less be computer data. Hence, they could constantly download additional data from the environment which would help them become stronger. If Digimon were to get deleted, they would essentialy break into many pieces of data which can be loaded by other Digimon.

This potentially would trigger a Digivolution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask where you get this info? Is this just your guess?

Comment: With regard to Digimon being computer data, it is more or less established where each version of the Digimon Anime is set in a different world. I'm assuming you are aware of the reincarnation cycle of Digimon in general. In Digimon Data Squad & Tamers, we see digimon data being absorbed by others. One good example of Digivolution being triggered by absorbtion is Lucemon who absorbs his Royal Knights and evolves to his Chaos mode.

Comment: ah I see. But do we have example of Digimon absorbing other Digimon data to digivolve to a fuse form?